# How strong are the Marine Admirals?

Tags: one-piece

Since the Navy mainly determines power through bounty.  They seem strong but Whitebeard was able to fight all three admirals at one.  Also the Commanders of Whitebeard were on par with the Admirals. So how strong are the Admirals?  How much bounty would they get if they got one?

Comment: Have you watched Aokiji and Akainu fight on an island named *Punk Hazard*? One side of that big island turned into lava and volcanic mountains, and the other to ice just after their ten day fight. Their power when they got serious is crazy, its just that they're not showing their real power yet. And, finally Akainu becomes the new fleet admiral, and Aokiji has resigned.

Comment: Bounty isn't related to power. It's related to the threat the person offers to the World Government. Look at young Robin or Blackbeard. Their bounties don't match their power at all. Iirc they marines even mention this when talking about Luffy's 2nd(?) bounty. Also after a while they don't bother increasing the bounty anymore, since it doesn't really serve a point. Whether it be 700 mil or 500 mil, the bounty hunters will probably even be less likely to hunt the 700 mil pirate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Navy actually doesn't determine bounty based entirely on power, they also base it on how badly they want the particular guy caught.

Considering how DonFlamingo's bounty was 340 million beli, and he was a pretty big deal,  It appears that the marines start leveling out the bounties around the 300-400 million range.

That taken into account, If the admirals were pirates, their bounties would likely be in the 300 million range.

As far as power goes (and power is not that quantifiable in one piece), they're all in the top league, and so far, the only character who was formally introduced who can be said to have a very clear advantage over the admirals is Whitebeard, and he's dead.

the Other Yonko are very likely to be stronger than any particular admiral, but that's not necessarily a concrete rule, and we yet to have a good measure of their power.

Comment: yes, but bounty also reflects on the power of the person.  You hardly would see a person with a bounty of 10 million bounty defeat a person with 100 million bounty, with the exceptions new devil fruit powers or a rookie.

Comment: @Blue  Blackbeard had a bounty of 0, due mostly to laying low

Comment: as I said in the comment, new devil fruit power.  Blackbeard was a nobody until he ate the yami yami fruit.

Comment: @Blue Except he was able to leave a scar on Shanks's face and get away with it.  He wasn't a nobody because he was week.  He was a nobody because he didn't make waves.

Comment: That was because of a sneak attack.  Shanks said that he let his guard down at that time too.

Comment: Sorry for very late comment but I must say this. Blackbeard is strong even without devil fruit, even with a sneak attack, one can not easily attack Shanks if he's that weak. Also, ace said himself that Blackbeard could fill the position for commanders of the Whitebeard Pirates. It mean at least he's fully capable to do so, and on same strength with other commanders, and he can do that without his devil fruit.

Comment: Shanks actually specifically said "It wasn't a fluke, I was being serious and he still left this scar."

Answer (score 6):

All of the Admirals are likely 1 step below the Four Emperors. I think it would be realistic to say that if Akainu was a pirate, he´d probably be around the 500-700 million range.

Aokiji is the least hostile and probably the weakest too, though it´s hard to say how they compare against each other.

Akainu is the most hostile and potentially the strongest of them. Lava is one of the most ridiculous powers imaginable, being both heavy enough to choke out fire and gas/air and still liquid, oh and it´s at least 1000 degrees Celsius as well.

What I want to say though is that I think Kizaru is the strongest of the Admirals. Think about this for a moment. You can counter ice with fire and other heat-related things or things that can´t be frozen. How the hell do you counter light? Light moves at 300 thousand kilometers a second (and therefore hits with that force too, making Kizaru potentially the physically strongest character in the One Piece world), is intangible, can bounce off of things, can cut and pierce things in the form of a laser. That´s probably the most overpowered possibly Devil Fruit power.

To put it shortly, while they aren´t the most powerful characters in the series, the Straw Hats probably still don´t stand a chance against one and they are pretty close to the top.

Comment: I actually think that the most powerful devil fruit is the Phoenix Phoenix fruit but whatever.

Comment: Marco´s Phoenix Fruit is incredibly powerful when it comes to defense but it has no killing power whatsoever. Kizaru is just as immortal as Marco but with the added benefit of retarded amounts of destructive power.

Comment: kizaru's pika pika no mi can be trolled easily by yami yami no mi. black hole doesn't let light to escape. Also kizaru was blocked easily by Rayleigh, ben beckman by simple haki.

Answer (score 0):

You know how in some stories there are some characters who are like, god-like overpowered? Thats how the admirals are. When luffy was fighting aokiji, the latter was barely using his full power and easily owned him. Its difficult to hit them since they can turn into their own element (except by using sea stone or haki), but the element akainu turns into probably makes him more dangerous. If you touch ice, part of you will freeze. Light, nothing will happen. Magma? your body will evaporate and die. I'd say Aokiji's powers are more accurate, Akainu's are more destructive, while Kizaru is a combination of both, but I think he kinda balances. I'd say currently in one piece they're all equal. Sure, it did take 10 days for Akainu to beat Aokiji, but with that much time they barely seemed to have been outmatched.